# How to remove double quotes when it comes within double quotes

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a data like this

```
"Apple grape","Banana"orange","Red green"
"Apple grape","Bananaorange","Red green"
```

I want to remove the single `"` quote which is present between `Banana` and `orange` using `awk` or `sed` command.

Comment: is there any comma inside double qoutes also? for example `"Banana,",orange"` in that case given answers will produce wrong result.

Comment: ... and do you have nested quotes? like `1,"",sometihng," ",3`?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all fields are quoted "on the outside", or can there be unquoted fields (see first and last field in αғsнιη's comment)?

Comment: In `"Apple grape",","Banana orange","Red green"` for instance, how do we decide between `"Apple grape,","Banana orange","Red green"` (remove the extra `"` in `"Apple grape","`) and `"Apple grape",",Banana orange","Red green"` (remove the extra `"` in `","Banana orange"`)?

Comment: Can your quoted fields also contain newlines? An unescaped `"` in the middle of a field is not valid in any CSV "standard" (e.g. [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) or as can be generated by MS-Excel), it needs to be escaped as `""` or `\"`, so you should fix whatever is generating those invalid CSVs.

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
sed 's/\([^,]\)"\([^,]\)/\1\2/g' file
```

This would replace all non-overlapping sequences of not-a-comma (`[^,]`), double-quote, and not-a-comma, with the same thing, but without the double quote.

This would not handle situations where the pattern would match at overlapping substrings, as in, for example, `...""...` and  `..."."...`. I'm leaving that for now as it's not clear that these cases may occur in the user's data. Running the substitution twice would resolve these cases.

Output is produced on the terminal, so redirect to a file if you want to save it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have no commas or newlines within your fields and all of your fields are double quoted as in your example then using any sed in any shell on every Unix box you could do:

```
$ sed 's/"//g; s/,/","/g; s/.*/"&"/' file
"Apple grape","Bananaorange","Red green"
```

Answer (score 1):

The double quote(s) we are after, will always have neighbors on both of its sides. And the neighbors will always be noncomma. But since sed doesn't do lookarounds, so the regex will consume input. Hence we must loop.

```
sed -Ee '
  :loop
    s/([^,])"([^,])/\1\2/
  tloop
' file
```

---

Perl with lookarounds makes it concise.

```
perl -lpe 's/(?<=[^,])"(?=[^,])//g' file
```

---

Alternatively, we transform the double quotes utilised in forming the field separators. Then what quotes stand out  are the ones to go. Then we reverse transform.

```
sed -Ee '
  s/^"|","|"$/\n/g
  s/"//g
  s/^\n|\n$/"/g
  s/\n/","/g
' file
```

Note: GNU sed with extended regex -E is used.

Comment: The `"`'s neighbours are only guaranteed to be non-commas if the fields are guaranteed not to contain commas.

Comment: If comnas are allowed then the seq quote comma quote would rupture the field and start a new one. And since no such scenario was mentioned so I took the liberty of forbidding comnas midfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```bsh
$ sed 's/"\([^,"]*\)"\([^,"]*\)"/"\1\2"/g' foo.txt 
"Apple grape","Bananaorange","Red green"
"Apple grape","Bananaorange","Red green"
```

Answer (score 0):

Whith GNU `awk` using `gensub()` function:

```
awk  '{print gensub(/([[:alpha:]]+)"([[:alpha:]]+)/,"\\1\\2","g")}' file
"Apple grape","Bananaorange","Red green"
"Apple grape","Bananaorange","Red green"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with `gawk` and `mawk`:

```
awk -F, '$2~/[a-z]"[a-z]/ { split($2, a, "\""); for (i in a) n2 = n2 a[i]; $2 = "\"" n2 "\"" }1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/Banana.*orange/Bananaorange/g' filename
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `.*` syntax is a wildcard that would replace any number of characters, and not *just* a double-quote.

Comment: Note that given data is an _example_. The user says "I have data _like_ this", which means that their data may look slightly different but that it contains embedded double quote characters.